# ESPN nba athlete api unknown regex and syntax error

Tags: ruby, json, api

Using curl http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/?apikey=MY_API_KEY}) in the terminal works.

When I try to parse it in a file. I get the following error.

```
nba_player_stats.rb:11: unknown regexp options - ap
nba_player_stats.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

This is my code in the file. I required "json" and "net/http"

```
uri = URI(http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/?apikey=My_API_KEY})                                        
raw_data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)                                                                                                                                                                        
json = Json.parse(raw_data)
```

I'm not quite sure what the error is. If it's working fine with curl I feel it should work in my ruby file.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: The question was why do I get the following errors, but I solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uri = URI(http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/?apikey=My_API_KEY})
```

Is wrong. Try:

```
uri = URI('http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/?apikey=My_API_KEY')
```

Or:

```
uri = URI.parse(...)
```

The problem is, you are supposed to use a string for URI's parameter, but you didn't. Your parameter is the raw URL text, without any quotes, which Ruby tries to interpret as a variable and/or a regular expression, then gives up and returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Two 2 problems. 
1. The url was not in quotes.The url needs to be in quotes.

```
uri = URI("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/?apikey=My_API_KEY}")
```

2. API_Key was not in quotes